# how to add/remove calculated % on certain row

Tags: r

This question has two parts, please read through it. Thanks.

I have  a data.frame that looks like this:

[image]

I want to know whether there is simple way to remove everything in () ,the outcome will looks like this:

[image]

I am thinking sth like:

```
gsub("(\\s*\\(\\w+\\))", "", df)
```

This one doesn't work. I want to remove all () in df.

Then if we have df as table 2, is there an easy way to add calculated % in the (). Basically I want to do the reverse , try to get table 1 from table 2. the percentage within () is calculated using the number in each cell/ value in row1.

The sample data can be build using codes:

```
df <-structure(list(Total = c("159", "159", "131 (82.39%)", "92 (57.86%)", 
"89 (55.97%)", "81 (50.94%)"), `20/20 mg/m2` = c("3", "3", "2 (66.67%)", 
"2 (66.67%)", "1 (33.33%)", "0 (0%)")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is perfectly identical to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65695190/3358272) that was marked as a duplicate. In fact, I just tried the first (highest-scoring) answer on the question/answer linked to in the close-as-dupe, replaced its string value with `df[[2]]`, *and it worked perfectly*. Closing as a duplicate does not reflect negatively on the question itself, and is meant to keep that existing question as the primary one found. No, this is still a duplicate.

Comment: Okay, I'll relax a moment ... since you finally added something that was not answered in that dupe.

Comment: I think my questions has two parts, not just simple remove () . That is why I hope to get some suggestion.

Comment: Your first part is answered in the dupe, you should not include that as a question (otherwise you'll get comments like mine).

Comment: (Realize that many users will notice when you ask a question, it gets closed, then the same question gets asked a few minutes later. It doesn't happen all the time, but it is not without notice.)

Comment: the reason I asked the same question twice as I don't think my question is the same as the one you provided. It has two parts, back and forth. Many people might not have the patient to read through it. That is why when I post my old question again, I added "This question has two parts, please read through it."

Comment: Yes, I understand. Your question was untouched for over 10 minutes with precisely the same words and images and such. I'm saying that you need to fix/change it *before* you post the second question. Either way, I'm glad you resolved that portion and were able to get a quick answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 1st part you can use `readr::parse_number` to get the first number from the data.

```
library(dplyr)

part1 <- df %>% mutate(across(.fns = readr::parse_number))
part1

#  Total 20/20 mg/m2
#1   159           3
#2   159           3
#3   131           2
#4    92           2
#5    89           1
#6    81           0
```

To generate part2 you can divide all numbers by 1st number and arrange them using `sprintf`.

```
part2 <- part1 %>% 
           mutate(across(.fns = ~sprintf('%.2f (%.2f %%)', .x, .x/.x[1] * 100)))
part2
#             Total     20/20 mg/m2
#1 159.00 (100.00 %) 3.00 (100.00 %)
#2 159.00 (100.00 %) 3.00 (100.00 %)
#3  131.00 (82.39 %)  2.00 (66.67 %)
#4   92.00 (57.86 %)  2.00 (66.67 %)
#5   89.00 (55.97 %)  1.00 (33.33 %)
#6   81.00 (50.94 %)   0.00 (0.00 %)
```

Comment: Those two are very useful! never thought of it. much easier than `gsub`

Comment: Is it a way to remove the first two rows' () in part 2  or only do the calculation starting from row 3?

Comment: Yes, you can use `ifelse` : `mutate(across(.fns = ~ifelse(row_number() > 2, sprintf('%.2f (%.2f %%)', .x, .x/.x[1] * 100), .x)))`